# grapgql-ruby using the graphiql interface on a Rails 5 api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql-ruby, graphiql

This is probably something stupid simple, but not sure how to run the graphiql interface when working with a rails api. Possible this might not be feasible as when i installed the gem, it made reference to not installing graphiql i believe because it detected i was using a api. I did tho manually install the gem:

```
  gem 'graphiql-rails', '1.4.4'
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you only need agree this gem https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby and add the next code in routes.rb

```
if Rails.env.development?
  mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphiql", graphql_path: "/graphql"
end
```

and to auto load the types need agree this

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('graphql', 'types')
```

after that, run rails s and on 0:0:0:0:3000/graphiql should be show the interface